# Block PDF,DOCX, XLSX download, allow print

Tags: pdf

in our online laboratory software (php) we want to upload some files and allow users to print these documents. Bu we have to block downloading them, because user can print from downloaded file, if we upload newer version of document this will be a problem. 
Is there any way to block downlodin these documents?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you ask for is possible, because I can always print a file as pdf to my desktop instead to my printer if I wanted. My organisation handles this issue by having a watermark on all PDF files that says "Uncontrolled copy when printed", so even if someone prints it out they will know that it might be outdated and should be careful.